# magento 2 - need to change text and remove items from wishlist

Tags: magento2, admin-panel, inline-translations

Hi i'm not developer so please help. i'm trying to change 'My Wish List'   to   'wishlist' and wanna remove 'items'

My Wish List 2 items  - wishlist 2

Comment: Check this link, hope it helps https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/245215/rename-shipping-address-into-delivery-address-magento2-checkout-page/245243#245243

Answer (score 5):

To change the label for 'My Wish List' to 'wishlist' , go to vendor/magento/module-wishlist/i18n/your_language.csv (i think there will be en_us only)
And change:

```
"My Wish List","My Wish List"
```

to

```
"My Wish List","wishlist"
```

Okay, so if want to change as in the screenshot, goes to the same file and change this as you want.

```
"%1 items","%1 items"
```

to

```
"%1 items","%1"
```

This will implement the change that you want, also you have to do in the line before that is `"1 item","1 item"`and remove the second item if you want to remove in case that there is only 1 item in the cart.

If you make the site multilanguage, don't forget to make the correct translations of this or this will appear in the other languages.

Comment: thank you i m working on new theme. please check screenshot http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/1253785/1a8292fd3567fcdb8297da6efa6c74d2    

is there any easy way to change on phtml or some file?

Comment: edited the response as you want.

Comment: thank you @ntzz it works perfect. i've another question. how to re-order top links.   

My Account  WishList  Sign In   to WishList My Account   Sign In

Comment: @RawiRai as far as i know isn't possible. There is an issue with Magento 2 to make it possible, i had ask in github for it now, see on: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/2354

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't want to make the csv edit in core module. How is it possible to extend the core file module .csv file.? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You dont wanna write a preference if you can write a plugin like.
You can download the module from this link https://mage2gen.com/load/31b0b02d-c02e-47ae-b6e1-bbd967930509 make sure to replace the plugin with code below.

```
namespace [Vendor]\Wishlist\Plugin\Magento\Wishlist\CustomerData;

class Wishlist
{

/**
 * @var \Magento\Wishlist\Helper\Data
 */
private $wishlistHelper;

/**
 * Wishlist constructor.
 * @param \Magento\Wishlist\Helper\Data $wishlistHelper
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Wishlist\Helper\Data $wishlistHelper
) {
    $this->wishlistHelper = $wishlistHelper;
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function afterGetSectionData(
    \Magento\Wishlist\CustomerData\Wishlist $subject,
    $result
) {
    $result['counter'] = $this->wishlistHelper->getItemCount();
    return $result;
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is best way to archive this task.

'%1 items' text is coming from [createCounter] function from Wishlist class we only need to create preference for this.

```
\Magento\Wishlist\CustomerData\Wishlist
```

1.di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<preference for="Magento\Wishlist\CustomerData\Wishlist" type="\Namespace\Modulename\CustomerData\Wishlist" />
</config>
```

Whishlist.php

```
 <?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Namespace\Modulename\CustomerData;


class Wishlist extends \Magento\Wishlist\CustomerData\Wishlist
{
   public function __construct(
       \Magento\Wishlist\Helper\Data $wishlistHelper,
       \Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Sidebar $block,
       \Magento\Catalog\Helper\ImageFactory $imageHelperFactory,
       \Magento\Framework\App\ViewInterface $view
   ) {
       parent::__construct($wishlistHelper, $block, $imageHelperFactory, $view);
   }

    protected function createCounter($count)
    {
        if ($count > 1) {
            return __('%1', $count);
        } elseif ($count == 1) {
            return __('1');
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

This one is the best way rather than changing in language file.