# Rename shipping address into delivery address-magento2 checkout page

Tags: magento2

In my checkout page,i need to rename shipping address.i used IWD free extenstion for one step checkout.here with i enclose the screenshot and link to IWD free one step checkout link.Refer(https://www.iwdagency.com/extensions)[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it easily from backend -

**1)** Navigate to **Stores > Configuration > Developer > Translate Inline** in magento admin and set **YES** to **Enable for Storefront**.

as shown in below image -

[image]

**2)** Now go to frontend checkout page, it will be shown like this-

[image]

click on book icon underneath "Shipping Address" text.

**3)** A panel will be shown like below image, there you can change text "Shipping Address" and click Submit button and refresh the page. You will see the changed text.

[image]

[image]

**4)** At last set "No" to field "Enabled for Storefront".

put your comments if you get any problem.

Comment: great!!!!it's working....

Comment: sounds good!!! please mark this as correct answer then .

Answer (score 1):

Go to app/design/frontend/YourTheme/default/i18n/en_US.csv and add

**"Shipping Address","Delivery Address"**

after that run below command

**php bin/magento cache:clean && php bin/magento cache:flush**

OR

if you don't have custom theme then just get from [here](https://github.com/hitesh-srtpl/magento225-demo/tree/master/app/design/frontend/Srtpl/default) and run below command

**php bin/magento setup:upgrade && php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f**

Comment: it's not working..i copy i18n into my custom theme..

Comment: Did you run php bin/magento cache:clean && php bin/magento cache:flush command? also try with run php bin/magento setup:upgrade && php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f command it should work I tested it.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to change the label is by **Translation**.

You only need to create i18N folder in your app/code/***namespace***/***module_name*** and just create one CSV file named `en_US.csv` write translation script in it. Do something like this:

```
"Shipping Address","Delivery Address"
```

Answer (score 0):

Override Below template in your theme like as

> app/design/frontend/vendor/themename/IWD_Opc/frontend/web/template/shipping.html

and change one line on that file

```
<div class="iwd_opc_universal_wrapper iwd_opc_column_name" data-bind="i18n: 'Shipping Address'"></div>
```

to

```
<div class="iwd_opc_universal_wrapper iwd_opc_column_name" data-bind="i18n: 'Delivery Address'"></div>
```

Or do it by translation like as below process

1.create **en_US.csv** or **en_GB.csv** as your requirement in the path app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/i18n

2.then run below command for generate translate csv

> php bin/magento i18n:collect-phrases
>   --output="/var/www/html/magento2/app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/i18n/en_GB.csv"
>   /var/www/html/magento2/app/design/frontend/vendor/themename

3.Now write row in csv "Shipping Address","Delivery Address"

Bow run commands like as below

```
 php bin/magento setup:upgrade
 php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US en_GB -f
 php bin/magento cache:flush
```