# Add label to the text field-magento2 checkout field

Tags: magento2, checkout, third-party-module

I want to add labels in the checkout page text fields.I used IWD free extension for one step checkout.here with i enclose the screenshot and link to IWD free extension. Refer `https://www.iwdagency.com/extensions`

[image]

Comment: please check this here  - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/245215/rename-shipping-address-into-delivery-address-magento2-checkout-page/245243#245240

Comment: i want to create a label,not rename already existing label..

Comment: you mean you want to add an additional text field on checkout page ?

Comment: yes...additional label to the text field.for example->email:[textfield]

Comment: not additional textfield...additional label

Comment: you should try this- go to module directory IWD/Opc/i18n/en_US.csv 
and  write this there **"Email Address" : "Custom label"**  and save file and clear cache.

Comment: It changes the placeholder value of textfield.but i need to include one label beside the textfield

Answer (score 0):

Fast way: in file Block/Checkout/Update LayoutProcessor.php
Add label for necessary field.
[image]

And get label in this file 
view/frontend/web/template/form/element/email.html
[image]

Comment: Perfect,It's working.......Thankyou

Comment: can you please tell how to remove textfield from checkout page.